# How to create Tkinter widgets with loop and assign custom functions to each of them?

Tags: python, loops, variables, optimization, tkinter

This is my first python app and I'm aware of many of it's flaws so I'll try to learn on my mistakes.

I would like to understand how to shorten my code a bit by putting declaration of tkinter widgets in a loop.

Here is part of the code(there is quite large list of similar sections, but I would just apply same logic):

```
varplies = StringVar(root)
varnotch = StringVar(root)
varspreader = StringVar(root)
varorder1 = StringVar(root)
varorder2 = StringVar(root)
def pliesto_uppercase(*args):
    varplies.set(varplies.get().upper())

def notchto_uppercase(*args):
    varnotch.set(varnotch.get().upper())

def spreaderto_uppercase(*args):
    varspreader.set(varspreader.get().upper())

def order1to_uppercase(*args):
    varorder1.set(varorder1.get().upper())

def order2to_uppercase(*args):
    varorder2.set(varorder2.get().upper())

varplies.trace_add('write', pliesto_uppercase)
varnotch.trace_add('write', notchto_uppercase)
varspreader.trace_add('write', spreaderto_uppercase)
varorder1.trace_add('write', order1to_uppercase)
varorder2.trace_add('write', order2to_uppercase)
self.rnplies_entry = Entry(self.entry_frame, background=rgbcon2((158, 174, 179)),
                           justify='center', textvariable=varplies, width=4)
self.rnnotch_entry = Entry(self.entry_frame, background=rgbcon2((158, 174, 179)),
                           justify='center', textvariable=varnotch, width=4)
self.rnspreader_entry = Entry(self.entry_frame, background=rgbcon2((158, 174, 179)),
                              justify='center', textvariable=varspreader, width=4)
self.rnorder1_entry = Entry(self.entry2_frame, background=rgbcon2((158, 174, 179)),
                            justify='center', textvariable=varorder1, width=8)
self.rnorder2_entry = Entry(self.entry2_frame, background=rgbcon2((158, 174, 179)),
                            justify='center', textvariable=varorder2, width=8)
self.rnplies_entry.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=5, sticky="SEW")
self.rnnotch_entry.grid(column=2, row=5, padx=5, sticky="SEW")
self.rnspreader_entry.grid(column=5, row=5, padx=5, sticky="SEW")
self.rnorder1_entry.grid(column=0, row=9, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="SEW")
self.rnorder2_entry.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="SEW")



pfdate = StringVar(root)
pfdate.set('All')
pfmarker = StringVar(root)
pfmarker.set('All')
pfdate.trace('w', partial(changeplan, widget=pfdate))
pfmarker.trace('w', partial(changeplan, widget=pfmarker))
def planfilters():
    pdatelist = plandatefilter()
    pmarkerlist = planmarkerfilter()
    self.drop_datepl = OptionMenu(self.optionplan_frame, pfdate, *pdatelist)
    self.drop_datepl.config(bg=rgbcon2((39, 46, 46)), width=10, fg='white')
    self.drop_datepl.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="E", padx=5, pady=5)
    self.drop_rnpl = OptionMenu(self.optionplan_frame, pfmarker, *pmarkerlist)
    self.drop_rnpl.config(bg=rgbcon2((39, 46, 46)), width=22, fg='white')
    self.drop_rnpl.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="E", padx=5, pady=5)
```

In short, I would like to understand how to put it in the loop to be like for example:

```
pl_filters = ('pfdate', 'pfmarker')
for opt_item in pl_filters:
    pl_filters[opt_item] = StringVar(root)
    pl_filters[opt_item].set('All')
    pl_filters[opt_item].trace('w', partial(changeplan, widget=pl_filters[opt_item]))
```

Comment: keep elements in dictionary instead of using many different variables.

Comment: or create own widget with all needed elements and then use this widget in loop.

Comment: to see how to use loop better group element which use the same var - ie. `StringVar and trace and Entry and grid which use the sama varaible` - instead of grouping by type - ie. all StringVar`, next all Entry, next all grid. This way you will see similar parts of code

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What is wrong with the code in the last example?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, because: `pl_filters[opt_item] = StringVar(root)
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`. What @furas suggested and @Henry Yik answered was exactly what I've need. I just need to modify it a bit to suit my needs.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't look closely enough at `pl_filters`, I was assuming it was a dictionary. All you need to do is switch that to a dictionary, or create a new dictionary. This has nothing to do with tkinter, it's just normal python at this point.

Comment: Later I investigated, but already used @Henry Yik solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the first part of your code, it looks like you are using the `trace` method on your `StringVar` just to convert the inserted characters to upper case. If so, I recommend implementing your own class with such method built in so you can avoid the need to create them later.

Also, you can create your `StringVar` and `Entry` in a for loop. Just save those references in a list for later use if required.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class CustomVar(tk.StringVar):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.StringVar.__init__(self)
        self.trace("w",self.trace_method)

    def trace_method(self,*args):
        self.set(self.get().upper())

class Something(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master,**kwargs)
        all_vars = [CustomVar() for _ in range(5)] #create 5 vars in one go
        entries = []
        for num, var in enumerate(all_vars,1): #loop through the vars and create entries
            entry = tk.Entry(self,background="yellow",justify="center",
                             textvariable=var,width=4 if num <4 else 8)
            entries.append(entry)

        for num, cords in enumerate(((1,5),(2,5),(5,5),(0,9),(0,10))): #your grid row and column number grouped in a tuple
            entries[num].grid(column=cords[0],row=cords[1],padx=5,sticky="SEW")

a = Something(root)
a.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Just need to update rest of the code too! I'll return with result! Thnx

Comment: Well done! Exactly what I've needed. I modify it a bit to fit my code but that's it! I have a small issue with **kwargs and **args during py to exe in pyinstaller but that is another problem I need to investigate!